# 3G modem recognized as CD ROM

Tags: usb-modem

1. How can I identify whether a USB 3G dongle was recognized as a CD ROM or modem?
2. How can I switch to modem mode in case it was recognized as CD ROM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check using dmesg, it will print a different message ( I do not have a 3g modem handy to show you, but just run dmesg -w , plug the modem and see what was printed when you plugged it, if it speak of cdrom or sda, sdb, etc, then this is seen as a cdrom )

And usb_modeswitch is the tool used by most Linux system to switch the modem from one mode to the other. If it doesn't switch automatically, it may be worth reporting a bug to add the support ( usually, just the ID of the modem ).